# Why my app keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash, imagebutton

Here is the LogCat, hope it helps:

```
> 01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.guzi.uyproductions/com.guzi.uyproductions.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at com.guzi.uyproductions.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>         01-15 04:10:50.154: E/AndroidRuntime(369):    ... 11 more
>         01-15 04:10:52.874: I/Process(369): Sending signal. PID: 369 SIG: 9
```

And this is the .java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent viewIntent =
          new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
            Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
          startActivity(viewIntent);
      }
    });
```

If you need more details, let me know

Comment: As in Log :`ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton` means `imageButton2` is `ImageButton` instead of `Button` . so use `ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);`

Comment: hi if problem will be solved than accept the answer that we can move to next question and others can also get help from the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi remove this line `Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);`

and use

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton )findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
```

you need to use `ImageButton`  but you are using `Button`

Answer (score 2):

As Jitesh already explained I just want to add a little point to remove some confusions.

From the name of ImageButton we may think that it is a subclass of Button class (Like textview is to View class). That's why this problem may occur from misconception. As we know we can cast a subclass to it's super class.

But ImageButton is not a subclass (neither direct nor indirect) of Button class So you cannot do the casting like you did. Here a ClassCastException is occuring.

Comment: yes!! StinePike is absolutely correct,+1 from my side, Button and ImageButton are having different superclasses..we can visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html